# react-final-form how does Field access some initial value?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

Assume my **App** component looks like:

```
import { Form } from "react-final-form";

myInitData = {
    firstName: "akira",
    lastName: "fubuki"
}

render() {
    return 
        <Form
            initialValues={myInitData} 
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            validate={this.validate}
          >
                {({handleSubmit, submitting, values}) => (

                    <MyComponentOuter
                        someProp1={100}
                        someProp2={200}
                    />

                )}
        </Form>
}
```

Furthermore, I have some component **MyComponentInner** within **MyComponentOuter** so the hierarchy is App => MyComponentOuter => MyComponentInner

**MyComponentInner** looks like:

```
class MyComponentInner extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(????) //how do i get access to firstName here..?
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <label>first name</label>
            <Field
              name="firstName"
              component="input"
              type="text"
            />
        )
    }
}
```

My questions are:

a) How does react-final-form's  component get access to "firstName" property automagically? (no props were passed to it explictily).

b) I want to access the same firstName value within MyComponentInner; what's the syntax, for example, if i want to console.log firstName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) It uses [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). The `<Form>` component holds a `final-form` object that manages all your form state for you, and the `<Field>` component uses `context` to talk to the form state.

b) Something like this would do it. The render function given to `Field` is provided with all of these [`FieldRenderProps`](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#fieldrenderprops).

```
<Field name="firstName">
  {
    ({ input } /* FieldRenderProps */) => {
      console.log(input.value)
      return null // render nothing (this is a render function)
    }
  }
</Field>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Just to be clear, so i am not able to extract the underlying firstName value outside of <Field/> as i tried to do in my question inside componentDidMount() ?